# How to prove following two statements are equivalent in Hilbert System?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

statement 1: $Γ$ is satisfiable implies $Γ$ is consistent.

statement 2: If $Γ$ derives $α$ then $Γ$ entails $α$.

I can easily prove statement 1 from 2 , but not 2 from 1 (without using strong completeness theorem).

Comment: Try: $\Gamma$ entails $\alpha$ iff $\Gamma \land \lnot \alpha$ is unsatisfiable, $\Gamma$ derives $\alpha$ iff $\Gamma \land \lnot \alpha$ is inconsistent.